# fillna the missing values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, scikit-learn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ9Gl.png)

LotFrontage column have relationship with LotArea
the values of LotFrontage is between 0.005% - 0.01% of the LotArea.

I am trying to get the random values between 0.005% - 0.01% of LotArea where LotFrontage is missing.

Example: In the pic at 1019 index values is missing for LotFrontage. I want to fill it with LotArea value 8978 * 0.005  to 8978 * 0.01

Code(to solve this issue):

```
np.where(df_train[df_train["LotFrontage"].isnull()], np.random.rand(df_train['LotArea']*0.005, df_train["LotArea"]*0.01),df_train["LotFrontage"])
```

```
Error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-49a940deebcd> in <module>()
----> 1 np.random.rand(df_train['LotArea'] *0.005,df_train["LotArea"] * 0.01)
mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.rand()
mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.random_sample()
_common.pyx in numpy.random._common.double_fill()
TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

LotArea = np.arange(100, 200, 10)
LotFrontage = np.array([np.nan, *[11, 13, 14, 5], np.nan, *[18, 19, 26, 12]])
df_train = pd.DataFrame({"LotArea": LotArea, "LotFrontage": LotFrontage})
df_train.LotFrontage = df_train.LotFrontage.apply(
    lambda x: df_train.LotArea.sample(n=1).to_numpy()[0]
    * np.random.randint(5, 10)
    / 1000
    if pd.isna(x)
    else x
)
print(df_train)
```

Than, we transform this:

```
     LotArea  LotFrontage
0      100          NaN
1      110         11.0
2      120         13.0
3      130         14.0
4      140          5.0
5      150          NaN
6      160         18.0
7      170         19.0
8      180         26.0
9      190         12.0
```

To this:

```
     LotArea  LotFrontage
0      100         0.48
1      110        11.00
2      120        13.00
3      130        14.00
4      140         5.00
5      150         0.76
6      160        18.00
7      170        19.00
8      180        26.00
9      190        12.00
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, i am getting inconsistent result data is not between this range  df_train['LotArea'] *0.005,df_train["LotArea"] * 0.01.

Comment: Is there any other way also? maybe some function in skLearn?
I am just curious to learn other ways also.

Comment: WORKING - just exchanged the this

lambda x: df_train.LotArea.sample(n=1).to_numpy()[0]
             `/ 1000   
             * np.random.randint(1, 5)`

Comment: Nice catch. I made the function be between 0.005 - 0.001 instead of 0.01. You can just change np.random.randint(1, 5) to np.random.randint(5, 10). I'll edit the answer. If I helped solving your problem, feel free to upvote and mark it as the solution. :)